# Problems building OpenHFT / Chronicle Queue

Tags: maven, build, queue, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I've been trying to build the latest release of chronicle queue (3.4.4), but keep running into dependency resolution failures.  Some of the dependencies SNAPSHOT versions are missing from the oss sonatype repository, etc.   Is there an "all" jar that one can use to build the entire product suite?  Any tutorial documenting the build process?

Answer (score 1):

In Chronicle-Queue repo you have different projects:

- Chronicle-Queue V3 (chronicle)
- Chronicle-Queue V4 (chronicle-queue)
- Demo
- tests

Chronicle-Queue V4 is incomplete and may effectively have dependencies problems whereas V3 should build fine. I suggest to build from Chronicle-Queue/chronicle